# Platform for creating unattended/automated training programs for new technology?

Tags: open-source, saas, dashboard, enterprise-portal

I am looking for a platform that will allow me to create training programs for large numbers of developers and testers that need to train their staff in using new technology. Both OpenSource or commercial SaaS will meet my needs.

The users would onboard themselves to the training they need and complete the modules without any human supervision. Progress would be automatically monitored and reported to management dashboards.

Key capabilities I am looking for:

- Create a training programme with multiple lessons and modules
- Allows users to onboard themselves to different training modules
- Allow management to purchase "credits" which can be used by users to complete the training
- Allow users to use disposable workspaces (e.g. GCP VMs or Docker containers) per lesson/module where they can learn the new technology by example and dispose of them after the lesson is completed
- Allow for "hooks" to check automatically if the lesson has been completed successfully by checking for proof of work in the disposable workspace (e.g. a specific task performed like creating an output file with specific content)
- A  high-level dashboard that allows the management to monitor how hundreds of people are progressing through the training

A good example of what I am looking for is [QwikLabls](https://www.qwiklabs.com), who have created a platform for training large groups of people on GCP usage in large enterprises.